# How create a xpath to target input based on other two value ('Amber' & '2')?

Tags: xml, selenium, web, web-scraping, xpath

I tried

```
//tbody/child::tr/td/span/span[text() = "Amber" and text() = "2"]
```

[image]

```html
  <tr class="">
<td class="width-50px"><label class="checkbox-custom checkbox-solo"><input name="27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968-select-bulk-edit" data-table-row-checkbox="true" type="checkbox" class="checkbox"><span class="checkbox-label strong"></span></label></td>
   <td class="width-20"><span class="align-with-btn"><span data-test-id="unsanitize">2</span> US</span></td>
   <td class="width-20"><span class="align-with-btn"><span data-test-id="unsanitize">Amber</span> </span></td>
   <td class="">
      <span>
         <div id="UNIFIED_27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968_price_field_wrapper" class="hide-xs hide-sm">
            <div class="has-validation tooltip-red  has-error" data-field="price-input" data-tooltip="Price must be between US$ 0.20 and US$ 50,000.00." id="UNIFIED_27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968_price_field">
               <div class="input-prepend"><span class="input-prepend-item">US$</span><input name="price-input" id="UNIFIED_27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968_price_field-input" required="" class="input input-min-width" style="padding-left: 42px;"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <button class="show-xs show-sm text-gray unstyled-button" tabindex="0" id="UNIFIED_27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968_price_label">US$ 0.00<span class="ss-etsy ss-write ml-xs-1 icon-smaller text-gray-lightest" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
      </span>
   </td>
   <td class="pl-xs-0 text-right">
      <div class="tooltip-top-right mt-xs-2"><input type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="switch-checkbox" id="switch-27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968"><label class="switch" for="switch-27433ee4-c66e-4237-8180-e293984bd968"><span class="screen-reader-only">Enabled</span></label></div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page? I can't see on picture you shared required elements

Comment: Can you share relevant html ?

Comment: @cruisepandey here is the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//td[.//td[contains(text(),'US')] and(.//td[contains(text(),'Amber')])]//input
```

Comment: actually I tried this, but it showed my 0/0 matching node.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
//span[text()='2']/../following-sibling::span/span[text()='Amber']/../following-sibling::span/descendant::input
```